# Chrome browser window.showModaldialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

I am using the javascript to open a child window using window.showModaldialog(), i have retuen a value from the child page is working fine in IE and firefox but is not working in chrome browser, is there any work around or alternative for it to work in chrome as well.

Comment: please provide code what you tried

Comment: Open the javascript console with errors on google to find the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Check this link.

http://codecorner.galanter.net/2014/09/02/reenable-showmodaldialog-in-chrome/

You can use:

```
function modalWin() {

if (window.showModalDialog) {

window.showModalDialog("xpopupex.htm","name",
"dialogWidth:255px;dialogHeight:250px");

} 

else {

window.open('xpopupex.htm','name',
'height=255,width=250,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,
continued from previous linemenubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no ,modal=yes');

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your popup blocker in Chrome. Should work just fine.

[image: Popup Blocker].